# how to understand the dmesg

Tags: rhel, hard-disk, disk, block-device, dmesg

we have redhat machine version 7.2 and each machine have disks

as

```
sdb
sdc
sdd
sde
sdf
```

in the dmesg report we get the following

```
[873080.996700] Buffer I/O error on device sdf, logical block 50575986
[873080.996702] Buffer I/O error on device sdf, logical block 50575987
[873080.996703] Buffer I/O error on device sdf, logical block 50575988
[873080.996705] Buffer I/O error on device sdf, logical block 50575989
[873080.996706] Buffer I/O error on device sdf, logical block 50575990
[873742.837309] sd 1:0:2:0: [sdf] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[873742.837324] sd 1:0:2:0: [sdf] tag#0 CDB: Write(16) 8a 00 00 00 00 00 18 24 50 88 00 00 01 18 00 00
[873742.837329] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdf, sector 405033096
[873742.837338] EXT4-fs warning (device sdf): ext4_end_bio:332: I/O error -5 writing to inode 160908517 (offset 860160 size 139264 starting block 50629172)
[873742.837342] Buffer I/O error on device sdf, logical block 50629137
[873742.837347] Buffer I/O error on device sdf, logical block 50629138
[873742.837350] Buffer I/O error on device sdf, logical block 50629139
```

I not sure if the disk - sdf is the problem here and need to replace it

Comment: Is not the error in English? What is the real purpose of the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, disk sdf is reporting errors on multiple blocks.  Replace it at the earliest opportunity.  You might want to also look into using `smartctl` to get stats on the disk failures

```
smartctl -a /dev/sdf
```

More detail at https://linux.die.net/man/8/smartctl and https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Analyzing_a_Faulty_Hard_Disk_using_Smartctl

Comment: what is the syntax to use - smartctl ?

Comment: about badblocks  , do you think badblocks  could find some errors that smartctl cant?